# backticks cannot work with Non-standard variable name in R

Tags: r

**Context**

I am fitting a logistic model with a non-standard variable name `Foot drop`.

The model can fit successfully when I change `Foot drop` to `Foot_drop`.

I do not understand why I cannot fit the model successfully using non-standard variable name `Foot drop`, although I used backtick such as `Foot drop`.

**Question**

How can I make backticks work with Non-standard variable name.

**Reproducible code**

```
data2 = structure(list(Recovered = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                     1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                                     1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                                     0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                     0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                       Foot_drop = c(">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                   ">6 weeks"), 
                       `Foot drop` = c(">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", ">6 weeks", "≤6 weeks", 
                                      ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks", ">6 weeks")), 
                  row.names = c(NA,  -107L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
fit1<-lrm(Recovered~Foot_drop,data=data2,x=T,y=T);print(fit1)   # work
fit2<-lrm(Recovered~`Foot_drop`,data=data2,x=T,y=T);print(fit2) # work
fit3<-lrm(Recovered~Foot drop,data=data2,x=T,y=T);print(fit3)   # not work
fit4<-lrm(Recovered~`Foot drop`,data=data2,x=T,y=T);print(fit4) # not work
```

Comment: What package is `lrm` from?

Comment: @Edward rms package

Comment: The `lrm` function doesn't appear to allow variable names with backticks. Suggest contact the package author and in the meantime, change the variable to `foot_drop`.